# pgfplots: dynamic path names in a foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to generate a couple of intersecting peaks with pgfplots with dashed/dotted paths where they overlap.
I'm having some trouble though with path names inside a foreach loop.
Here's the code:

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

    \usetikzlibrary{positioning, intersections}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{peak}{1}{%
      \pgfmathparse{abs(#1) > 1 ? 0 : cos((0.5*pi*#1) r)^3}%
    }%
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=400pt, height=250pt]

      % overlapping peaks
      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1,0,1}{
        \addplot [name path global = { line#1 },
        domain=#1-1:#1+1, samples=20, smooth, thick, black]
        {peak(x-#1)};
      }

      \path[draw=white, dotted, ultra thick,
      intersection segments={of=line1 and line0}];

      \path[draw=white, dotted, ultra thick,
      intersection segments={of=line0 and line-1}];

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I'd like to put the last two `path` calls inside some kind of loop. The issue is how to get the line names. Tried `line#1 and line#1-1` inside a pgfplots foreach but it doesn't work (obviously? it is still not so clear to me where math does and doesn't work with pgf), tried `line\i and line\i-1` in a `\foreach \i` loop. Doesn't work either...

Also tried putting the subtraction in a `\pgfmathparse{int(#1-1)}\pgfmathresult` pair but it always complains about missing `\endcsname`.

Any idea? Also any suggestion about better ways to achieve what I'd like are more than welcome... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below. This works by fully expanding the arguments for `\path` before it is called. Note that you are missing a `%` at the opening brace for `peak` which is shifting the entire plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{peak}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{abs(#1) > 1 ? 0 : cos((0.5*pi*#1) r)^3}%
    }%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=400pt, height=250pt]
        % overlapping peaks
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1,0,1}{%
            \addplot [name path = { line#1 },
            domain=#1-1:#1+1, samples=20, smooth, thick, black]
            {peak(x-#1)};
        }
        \foreach \x in {0,...,1}{%
            \pgfmathparse{int(\x-1)};
            \def\arg{of=line\x\space and line\pgfmathresult}%
            \edef\expath{\noexpand\path[draw=white, dotted, ultra thick,
                intersection segments={\arg}];}
            \expath%
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, I suspected I needed to expand the args but couldn't find how. Works perfectly now. Will edit the code to add the missing `%`

Answer (score 2):

A [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) alternative.  Simpler syntax?  you decide.  I've cheated slightly by plotting only one curve, then copying it by simply shifting it left and right.  The working of `intersectiontimes` is explained in the MP manual.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

vardef f(expr x) = if abs x > 1: 0 else: (cosd(90x))**3 fi enddef;

path xx, yy, line[];

xx = (left--right) scaled 220 shifted 20 down;
yy = (origin--up)  scaled 180 shifted point 0 of xx;

drawarrow xx withcolor .5 white;
drawarrow yy withcolor .5 white;

s = 1/32;
line2 = ((-1,f(-1)) for x=s-1 step s until 1: -- (x,f(x)) endfor) yscaled 150 xscaled 100;
line1 = line2 shifted 100 left;
line3 = line2 shifted 100 right;

numeric t[];
(t1,t2) = line1 intersectiontimes line2;
(t3,t4) = line2 intersectiontimes line3;

drawoptions(withcolor .67 red);
draw subpath( 0,t1)       of line1; 
draw subpath(t2,t3)       of line2;
draw subpath(t4,infinity) of line3;

drawoptions(dashed withdots scaled 0.7);
draw subpath(t1,infinity) of line1;
draw subpath(t3,infinity) of line2;
draw subpath(0,t2)        of line2;
draw subpath(0,t4)        of line3;

drawoptions();

endfig;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks! will keep it in mind, maybe for the next project. Too invested in tikz and pgfplots with this one to change now ;)